# Music folders don't have album covers as thumbnails

Tags: directory, music, thumbnails

Using Ubuntu 20 latest. When I open my folders and go to my music in my external hard disk, I can't see the image of the album in the album folder. Is there any way that I can see the image of the album so I can recognize the album I wanna play??

I know that I could do it by hand one by one, but I have a full TB of music...

For instance, when opening the album folder and all the songs pop up, in every single song, the image of the album is there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very unfortunately, such functionality is not there in the standard Gnome Desktop anno 2020. You may try a tool [Cover Thumbnailer](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/cover-thumbnailer-shows-folder.html), which is aimed to change icons for music folders to reflect the album art.

Comment: sounds awesome if I could use it, but when trying to install it seems that is a problem. I am trying to make a screenshot so u can see what it says.

Comment: Ok. now I have made it to work. I have install it again, and it works. thanks for your help

Comment: I probably should give it a go myself :-)

Comment: keeping trying it and seems that the nautilus get a bit slow and when coming back after been inside of a album folder, it comes back to the top of all my music, eventhough I was in the middle of the colums of music.